# Hibernate Collection vs List as field type

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, one-to-many

I have two entities, `Author` and `Book`, connected with a one-to-many relationship. What's the difference between specifying field type as `Collection<Book>` and `List<Book>`? Aforementioned scenario is presented below:

```
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private Collection<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(); // List<Book> instead?
}
```

The only difference I have already noticed is that when I want to use `@OrderColumn` annotation I need to use `List`, but are there any other differences I don't know about? Should I always use `Collection` if I don't need an order?

Comment: yes, you can use for unordered collection. @OrderColumn is for an ordered collection like the list.

Answer (score 2):

- Set -  contains no duplicates no order
- (Bag)Collection - duplicates no order
- List - duplicates order

For Set you need to be carefull about hashcode and equals. And one interesting twist with Bags in relation to SQL generated:

> If we are using List as a mapped attribute in hibernate without
>   indexed column, hibernates treats it as a Bag. Since Hibernate handles
>   List as a Bag (Unordered collection with non unique values. The best
>   feature of a bag is that you can get the number of occurrences of an
>   object through the API With a list, there is no way to do the same
>   without iterating through the whole list.) as soon as we delete and
>   add a element in this collection. Hibernate issues a SQL to delete all
>   the elements first from join table which are no supposed to be deleted
>   and then it re-insert all of them back from the Bag.

http://lkumarjain.blogspot.no/2013/07/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-entries.html

Comment: So if I understood correctly I shouldn't use List type without @OrderColumn annotation, right?

Comment: If you use a Join table yes. If you use JoinColumn without jointable this behaviour will not happen if the relation is bidirectional I forgot to say. Never use unidirectional OneToMany

Comment: Never use unidirectional OneToMany without having JoinTable.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Collection` is the most generic unordered collection of elements while the `java.util.List` implies existence of an iteration order.

Using `@OrderColumn` will give this iteration order however it might change the generated SQL query. Often it results in `ORDER BY` statement added to the SQL query. Without `@OrderColumn` the JPA provider has more flexibility but you should always measure the performance in your actual database instead of tuning it blindly.